# Javascript code don't disable elements on mobile like on desktop

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have the following code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<style>
html,body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,input {font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif}
</style>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqw.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


</head>
<body class="w3-light-grey">
<div class="w3-twothird" ng-app="wapp" ng-controller="inst">
    <div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
        <div class="w3-row">
            <div class="w3-col w3-container m1 l1 w3-center"></div>
            <div class="w3-col w3-container m10 l10 w3-wide">
<select ng-model="ngm" class="w3-select w3-border" name="something"><option value="" disabled selected>Choose something...</option>
        <option onclick="enable()" value="APPLE">APPLE</option>
        <option onclick="disable()" value="TOMATO">TOMATO</option>
        <option onclick="enable()" value="PEACH">PEACH</option>
        <option onclick="enable()" value="RICE">RICE</option>
</select>
<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<select class="w3-select w3-border" name="other"><option value="" disabled selected>Choose other...</option>
        <option value="JUICE">JUICE</option>
        <option id="notshow" value="RED">RED</option>
        <option value="TASTY">TASTY</option>
        <option value="LONG">LONG</option>
</select>
            </div>
            <div class="w3-col w3-container m1 l1 w3-center"></div>
        <div>

    <div>
Some text something:  <strong>{{ngm}}</strong>
<div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('wapp', []);
app.controller('inst', function($scope) {
    $scope.ngm = "Choose first thing";
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JS file (jqw.js) is that:

```
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("notshow").disabled=true;
}
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("notshow").disabled=false;
}
/*

 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("option").filter(".last").click(function () {
               //var content = $(this).html();
               $("#notshow").prop("disabled", true);
            });
         });


*/
```

I have tried with jquery first time, but no chance to make this to work on mobile browsers. On desktop browser work fine, but my problem is on mobile.
So, I need some help to see on mobile device too this action: when I select TOMATO option in the next select the option RED will be found disabled, or erased from there, from option list. No jQuery code worked so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. I modify the code, i use PHP. So now works fine! No help found here